# What does a pure expression mean in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have two questions. The first one: is `code` a pure expression?

```
lazy val code: Unit = {

    // block of code

    var s = "abc"
    for (i <- 0 until 10) println(i)
    s += s concat "def"
    println(s)

}
```

And the second one: What does a pure expression mean? Is this a some code which does not return anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pure expression is a computation that serves only to produce a resulting value - it has no side effects. In the case of your field `code` above, you make calls to print stuff to the console (`println`), which is considered a side effect, so it is not a pure expression. An example of a pure expression would be something like:

```
lazy val foo = 2 + 3
```

It does nothing apart from generate the final value for `foo`, and could safely be replaced by the result of the computation (`5`) without changing the outcome of the program in any way. If you made such a replacement in your code above:

```
lazy val code: Unit = ()
```

you would change the program - it no longer prints anything to the console.

Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), for example, for more information about pure functions and pure expressions, and their significance in functional programming.

Comment: Interesting! And what is the real type of `code`? The block contains four useful lines of code. I think it should be some object representation for such block. Am I right?

Comment: The type of `code` is as you have coded it: `Unit` (the equivalent of `void` in Java). It is not equal to the code block that defines it. Possibly you meant to use `def` instead of `lazy val`? That defines a function equal to the code block that follows, and can be called over and over (printing more lines to the console each time). Further calls to your lazy value above will just return `()` (the representation of the only instance of `Unit`), it won't re-execute the code block.

Comment: > **It is not equal to the code block that defines it**

Comment: if so, then why compiler infered the type of `code` as `Unit`? The block was assigned to code final variable, right?

Comment: OK, poor wording on my part perhaps: I meant that "the result of running the code block" is what is assigned to `code`, not "the code block" itself. As for the type of `code`: first, as written in your question, you have enforced the type yourself by writing `code: Unit`. That aside, the compiler can infer a type of `Unit` since the last statement in the code block - `println(s)` - has a type of `Unit`. The result (and type) of the last expression in a code block is taken as the result (and type) of the whole code block.